# Failover solution for web servers

Tags: high-availability

I'm looking for some failover solution between two web servers.

The web servers (CentOS+Nginx) are running on KVM virtualization platform.

I was testing RedHat high availability cluster but I've seen also tools like: HaProxy, Heartbeat, Keepalive.

- basically both web servers running the same content and the web root is sync with rsync.

Is it a good idea to install this software on the web nodes or should I create a separate guests for this purpose?

Can I use any of this tools for multi-site setup?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just use a load-balancer, that's what the vast majority of people do.

And there are multisite load-balancers around - I use Cisco GSSs.

Comment: I'm looking for some software solution as this staff is quite expensive.

Comment: You should include budget expectations in your questions.